# objective-c memory friendly way for background image

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks, background-image, memory-warning

i have an ipad app (>30 views / pages) each view has a unique background.

the problem:
whats the best way to set the background (memory friendly)

**is there a better way than adding: uiimageview "backgroundView" as a subview?**

version1:

```
[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
```

which seems to be problematic with the retina switch

version2:

```
self.layer.contents = (id)image.CGImage;
```

version 3:

```
UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:fileLocation];
```

**version 2 seems to work fine.** maybe someone tell me whats the best approach, and why ;)

thank you
Alex

Answer (score 1):

`CGImage` is problematic with retina ... version3. is best for memory friendly !

Answer (score 0):

In version 2, you generate a new image object which you have to release manually if you don't use ARC. Version 3 uses an autoreleased object.

Both versions are equal in memory-friendlyness.
I'd prefer version 3 because you don't have to do anything yourself to free the memory.

You could also use [UIImage imageNamed:@"image-name.png"], which also generates an autoreleased object.

If you want it as memory-friendly as possible, you should consider using PVR images, as those are natively supported by the graphics hardware.

Best,

Flo

Comment: hi, thanks for the quick response.
but imagenamend will eat up to much memory ;/
so i would need something like [self addSbview:UIIMAGEVIEW] aswell?
cause i wouldnt neet this in version 2?

Comment: Why is imageNamed too memory-consuming? I couldn't think of a reason why this constructor would create a bigger memory block than the other. Maybe I don't get your question right, but in either way you will have to load an image and assign it to either an image view or a CoreAnimation layer. I don't think that using an UIImageView creates that much of an overhead.

Comment: because the image is cached by the app. just google "imagenamed - memory leak"
well - actually it does create that much overhead on bigger apps.